# QPID ACL Invalid Syntax

Tags: acl, qpid

I'm using the Apached C++ QPID broker and it's failing to parse this rule:
`acl deny-log all all broker`.  *Tokens found after action "all"*
I'm trying to prevent anyone from modifying the broker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the C++ broker doesn't allow anything after `acl <permission> all all`. Brokers only have access and update permissions. The fix was to add:

```
acl deny-log all access broker
acl deny-log all update broker
```